# Merging data by group in R

Tags: r, merge, aggregate

I construct the following data.frame object:

```
name <- c("Homer", "Marge", "Bart", "Lisa", "Maggie")
incidents <- c(133, 36, 1242, 2, NA)
gender <- c("MALE", "FEMALE", "MALE", "FEMALE", "FEMALE")
data <- data.frame(name, incidents, gender)
```

yielding data =

```
    name incidents gender
1  Homer       133   MALE
2  Marge        36 FEMALE
3   Bart      1242   MALE
4   Lisa         2 FEMALE
5 Maggie        NA FEMALE
```

First I clean the data with

```
clean_data <- data[!is.na(incidents), ]
```

such that clean_data =

```
   name incidents gender
1 Homer       133   MALE
2 Marge        36 FEMALE
3  Bart      1242   MALE
4  Lisa         2 FEMALE
```

now I aggregate by gender with

```
agg <- aggregate(incidents ~ gender, clean_data, mean)
```

yielding

```
  gender incidents
1 FEMALE      19.0
2   MALE     687.5
```

Now, I'd like to be able to "fill in" the NA values in incidents with the data from agg such that data =

```
    name incidents gender
1  Homer       133   MALE
2  Marge        36 FEMALE
3   Bart      1242   MALE
4   Lisa         2 FEMALE
5 Maggie      19.0 FEMALE
```

What's the simplest way to do this using base R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `ave`.  It gives the "mean" values in the same order ("vals") as in the original dataset, check for the "NA" elements in "incidents" column and replace those with the "vals" for the corresponding "NA" element.

```
 vals <- with(data, ave(incidents, gender, FUN= function(x)
                                         mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)))
 indx1 <- is.na(data$incidents)
 data$incidents[indx1] <- vals[indx1]
```

A shorter version as showed by @MrFlick in the comments.  Using "ifelse", it replaces the "NA" elements with the "mean" value.

```
 data$incidents<-with(data, ave(incidents, gender,
          FUN=function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm=T), x)))
```

Instead of "ifelse", "replace" could be also used as @Ananda Mahto showed with "data.table".

Comment: I had the same idea but did `data$incidents<-with(data, ave(incidents, gender, FUN=function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm=T), x)))`

Comment: @MrFlick That looks much better.  You could post it as a new answer.  Actually, I didn't look at the results before I did the `ave`.

Comment: Honestly I think just using `ave()` on the complete data.frame is the "secret" here. My answer feels redundant.

Comment: What should the full solution be then? Have I performed too many steps?

Comment: @GeoffLittle  MrFlick's version is the shortest one.

Answer (score 4):

For variety, here's an approach with "data.table" that also demonstrates the `replace` function.

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(data)[
  , incidents := replace(incidents, is.na(incidents), 
                         mean(incidents, na.rm = TRUE)), 
  by = gender][]
#      name incidents gender
# 1:  Homer       133   MALE
# 2:  Marge        36 FEMALE
# 3:   Bart      1242   MALE
# 4:   Lisa         2 FEMALE
# 5: Maggie        19 FEMALE
```